# In simple terms, what are the major differences between P2WPKH and P2WSH bech32 addresses?

Tags: segregated-witness, bech32-address, p2wpkh, p2wsh

I've read over the [bip173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki), [bip141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki), and [bip143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki) specifications and they're a bit too technical to get at the simple answers I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you asking about the differences between P2WPKH/P2WSH in general, or about the differences between their corresponding address formats?

Comment: In short, both.  As you can see, I've added some of the research I've done over the past month or so.  I'm programming a bech32 encoder/decoder in perl, but also trying to understand bech32, segwit, P2WPKH, and P2WSH beyond simply porting the code from the node/c++ code in bip173.

Comment: Also, there were few simple and concise answers that I could find with a google search that correspond to bech32 validation and how bech32 relates to SegWit, so I wanted to share the conclusions I came to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **P2WPKH** - This stands for **"Pay To Witness Public Key Hash"** and the scriptPubkey is OP_0 0x14 {20-byte-hash}, where OP_0 is the version, byte 0x14 is the size of the data, and the {20-byte-hash} is a HASH160(PubKey).
- **P2WSH** - This stands for **"Pay To Witness Script Hash"**  and the scriptPubkey is OP_0 0x20 {32-byte-hash}, where OP_0 is the version, byte 0x20 is the size of the data, and the {32-byte-hash} is a SHA256(script).

This data is taken from: http://bcoin.io/guides/segwit.html

---

Examples:

For the **P2WPKH** address: "**bc1qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kv8f3t4**"

OP_0 , 0x14 , HASH160(PubKey) -- looks like (in hex):

00 14 751e76e8199196d454941c45d1b3a323f1433bd6

For the **P2WSH** address: "**bc1qrp33g0q5c5txsp9arysrx4k6zdkfs4nce4xj0gdcccefvpysxf3qccfmv3**"

OP_0 , 0x20 , SHA256(script) -- looks like (in hex):

00 20 1863143c14c5166804bd19203356da136c985678cd4d27a1b8c6329604903262

Examples taken from http://bitcoin.sipa.be/bech32/demo/demo.html and https://github.com/sipa/bech32/blob/master/ref/c%2B%2B/tests.cpp

Comment: Not MD5 (lol), it's SHA256.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I thought md5 sounded wrong myself!